# Shell script to start searching for pattern from a specific point and till end of file

Tags: shell

I was just wondering if you can please help here.

I have the following log file:

```
 qi3adm       20130701095302    : QI3/SYS/exe/uc/sunx86_64/tp import all
  QI3 u6 -Dsourcesystems=HRI,MP1,BFI,EBI,EBJ,EEI,EFI,EGI,EHI,EIA,EIC,EII,EIK,EIS

 qi3adm       20130701144746    : QI3/SYS/exe/uc/sunx86_64/tp import all
  qi3 u6 -Dsourcesystems=HRI,MP1,BFI,EBI,EBJ,EEI,EFI,EGI,EHI,EIA,EIC,EII,EIK,EIS

 qi3adm       20130701145155    : QI3/SYS/exe/uc/sunx86_64/tp import all
  QI3 u6 -Dsourcesystems=HRI,MP1,BFI,EBI,EBJ,EEI,EFI,EGI,EHI,EIA,EIC,EII,EIK,EIS

 qi3adm       20130701164041    : QI3/SYS/exe/uc/sunx86_64/tp import all
  QI3 u6 -Dsourcesystems=HRI,MP1,BFI,EBI,EBJ,EEI,EFI,EGI,EHI,EIA,EIC,EII,EIK,EIS

 qi3adm       20130701205821    : QI3/SYS/exe/uc/sunx86_64/tp import all
 QI3 u6 -Dsourcesystems=HRI,MP1,BFI,EBI,EBJ,EEI,EFI,EGI,EHI,EIA,EIC,EII,EIK,EIS

 qi3adm       20130702034725    : QI3/SYS/exe/uc/sunx86_64/tp import all
  QI3 u6 -Dsourcesystems=HRI,MP1,BFI,EBI,EBJ,EEI,EFI,EGI,EHI,EIA,EIC,EII,EIK,EIS
```

and my requirement is that I need to start searching only after the third entry in the logfile i.e. from

```
 qi3adm       20130701145155    : QI3/SYS/exe/uc/sunx86_64/tp import all
  QI3 u6 -Dsourcesystems=HRI,MP1,BFI,EBI,EBJ,EEI,EFI,EGI,EHI,EIA,EIC,EII,EIK,EIS
```

This logfile basically has thousands of records before the above record. I am able to pull out the above record using grep. After this I need to start searching only from the next record i.e. from

```
 qi3adm       20130701164041    : QI3/SYS/exe/uc/sunx86_64/tp import all
  QI3 u6 -Dsourcesystems=HRI,MP1,BFI,EBI,EBJ,EEI,EFI,EGI,EHI,EIA,EIC,EII,EIK,EIS
```

and continue searching till the end of the file. (and the hits need to be displayed). I was doing some search online and I tried using the following:

```
sed -e '/$TIMESTAMP/,$p' LOGFILE
```

[ $TIMESTAMP holds 2013 ]. However, the above doesn't give the correct output. The main problem I am running into is that the search needs to start only after record 3 and not from the beginning of the log file.

Can you please assist? Thanks a lot for your help.

Best Regards,
Sri

Answer (score 0):

With `awk`:

```
awk '/qi3adm       20130701164041/,0' logfile
```

With `sed`:

```
sed '/qi3adm       20130701164041/,$!d' logfile
```

Basically, you pass an expression in the start range and it will start from there on until the end of file.

Comment: You can shorten it to `awk '/20130701164041/,0' logfile` if you know which timestamp onwards you want to capture.

Comment: Hello JS, Thank you so much for your prompt reply. This worked! I was also just wondering if we can specify multiple patterns in the expression above. I was trying something like this: awk '/'$TIMESTAMP' && qi3adm && import/,0' . So basically these additional patterns need to checked and if they are present the line needs to be displayed. Thanks again for your help - Sri

Comment: You can certainly give multiple patterns but not like that. Here is a good [tutorial](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/An_Awk_Primer/Search_Patterns_(1)) to get you started with customized patterns

Comment: If your requirement is literally to start searching from the third line, `sed -n '3,$/pattern/p' logfile`

Comment: @tripleee Yeah that would have been my choice too but this line _This logfile basically has thousands of records before the above record._ in OP's question made me suggest a regex instead of line number.

Comment: Hello JS, Thanks for the tutorial. I have been trying to get this to work but still the output is not as desired. This is what I currently have:

Comment: qh1adm       20130711151154    : tp import all QH1 u6 -Dsourcesystems=BFI,EBJ

qx1adm       20130711151154    : tp count QX1 u6 -Dsourcesystems=B17,E17,EE7,E7S

qh1adm       20130711151155    : tp import all QH1 u6 -Dsourcesystems=E7B,B17

qh2adm       20130711151156    : tp import all QH2 u6 -Dsourcesystems=E7B,B17

emiadm       20130711151158    : tp count EMI u6 -Dsourcesystems=BFI,EBJ,EEI,

qh1adm       20130711151200    : tp import all QH1 u6 -Dsourcesystems=BFI,EBJ

In this case I want all the records starting from 20130711151154 and that have QH1 in them.

Comment: I tried the following:
awk '/'$STOPMARK'/ && /qh1adm/,0' logfile
awk '/'$STOPMARK'/ && /'qh1adm'/,0' logfile
where $STOPMARK holds 20130711151154. 

I also tried to use pipes but wasn't sure if that was correct.

My output should be the following:
qh1adm       20130711151154    : tp import all QH1 u6 -Dsourcesystems=BFI,EBJ
qh1adm       20130711151155    : tp import all QH1 u6 -Dsourcesystems=E7B,B17
qh1adm       20130711151200    : tp import all QH1 u6 -Dsourcesystems=BFI,EBJ

Can you please assist? Thanks a lot - Sri

Comment: @user2544767 Sorry but can you update your question. I cant understand from comments.

Comment: Hi JS, Sorry for the above. I tried to use the boolean && operator but somehow I am not getting the correct output. This is what I have as input:

Comment: qh1adm 20130711151154 : tp import all QH1 u6 -Dsourcesystems=BFI,EBJ 
qx1adm 20130711151154 : tp count QX1 u6 -Dsourcesystems=B17,E17,EE7 
qh1adm 20130711151155 : tp import all QH1 u6 -Dsourcesystems=E7B,B17 
qh2adm 20130711151156 : tp import all QH2 u6 -Dsourcesystems=E7B,B17 
emiadm 20130711151158 : tp count EMI u6 -Dsourcesystems=BFI,EBJ,EEI 
qh1adm 20130711151200 : tp import all QH1 u6 -Dsourcesystems=BFI,EBJ 
In this case I want all the records starting from 20130711151154 and that have QH1 in them.

Comment: So this should be output:  qh1adm 20130711151154 : tp import all QH1 u6 -Dsourcesystems=BFI,EBJ

qh1adm 20130711151155 : tp import all QH1 u6 -Dsourcesystems=E7B,B17

qh1adm 20130711151200 : tp import all QH1 u6 -Dsourcesystems=BFI,EBJ
  Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I have tried something like this: awk '/'qh1adm'/ && /'$STOPMARK'/,0' logfile Nothing seems to work though.

Comment: Hello JS, Thanks for your help. The search is now working. I am now trying to assign this awk output to an array. I will start a new thread for the same. Thanks again for all your help.